# How to parse json using SQL in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, sql

I'm looking to use SQL, in an Automation, to parse JSON data which is a JSON Array. I have 5M+ rows where I plan to parse the JSON data and write it to another DE where each `id` value is a separate row.

```
{
"items": [
{
"id": "dfa8eb26632ad060b978212abac639ad"
},
{
"id": "b523b2eb027edadad6fab9d5c265809f"
},
{
"id": "becb9c343c8741b4f9d47427a0edb024"
}
]
}
```

I've tried to use JSON_QUERY and have managed to get to the point where I've removed the array

`SELECT JSON_QUERY(@jsonData,'$.items') as itemList from tableName`

*result*

```
{
"id": "dfa8eb26632ad060b978212abac639ad"
},
{
"id": "b523b2eb027edadad6fab9d5c265809f"
},
{
"id": "becb9c343c8741b4f9d47427a0edb024"
}
```

I'm trying to get the output as a row for each "id" value:

```
dfa8eb26632ad060b978212abac639ad
b523b2eb027edadad6fab9d5c265809f
becb9c343c8741b4f9d47427a0edb024
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Am not a SQL Pro, but this would definitely help you. You are using the wrong function `JSON_QUERY` will return you again with an array. You need to use `JSON_VALUE` function to return a value.

Please find the below example which I have tried it in my instance:

**Inital Data Extension:**

I have added your JSON in one of my column

[image]

**SQL Query:**

```
Select JSON_VALUE(CustomerID,'$.items[1].id') as CustomerID from MyDE
```

**OR**
If you want to try with JSON_QUERY as well then use the below SQL :

```
Select JSON_VALUE(JSON_QUERY(CustomerID,'$.items'),'$[0].id') as CustomerID from MyDE
```

**Result:**

```
b523b2eb027edadad6fab9d5c265809f
```

I would suggest you to use SSJS using [ParseJSON](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformUtilityParseJSON.htm) function but i doubt it will support for 5 million rows.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that, however the actual JSON data is dynamic (number of id's can be between 1-20). Due to this fact, I can't use indexes to reference each id value.

I've managed to change the logic of the code that adds the data to the DE to put the ids in a csv value.
Not the best solution, but gets the job done (done using SSJS)

Comment: okay That's great!